#  Would I still get the Error reports on the market, while overriding the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: android, error-handling, google-play

I'm asking these question based on a hunch.

I've override the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, in my Android application, which is on the market.

I've had 3 updates, and added many new features, and although I didn't encounter any crash on a production version on the phone I develop with, I would expect a crash for whatever reason, since the application was installed on various devices and SDKs, now it can be that there are no exception, but since I override the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, I can't help but wonder, would I still get the error to the market error reports page?

I've also tried to build a production apk, in which I throw an exception intentionally and still overrides the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, and installed it on my development device.

I've launched it and it crashed :)

It has been an hour and I still can't see it on the error page.

- Would I still see the Exceptions in the Error report page if I
  override the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler?
- Does the error report ignores development device, even if a
  production version is installed?
- What is the refresh interval of the Error report service in the Android market?

Thanks in advance,

Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

Since it has been long enough, and I had time to consult people in my work place and run afew tests myself with the help of friend I got to the following conclusion:

Overriding the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, removes the Android Market error notification... how to add it back:

Get the DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler before setting the new one, and call the old one from the new one you have created...

The Error report does not ignore your development device.

and the refresh interval can be anywhere between 10 min and more.

Peace...